# Can't read data from appsettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to read data from *appsettings.json*.

`emailConfig` in `ApiController` is always null. I tried to read data using [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2) but it doesn't work.

Controller

```
private EmailConfiguration emailConfig;

public ApiController (IOptions<EmailConfiguration> _emailConfig) {

    this.emailConfig=_emailConfig.Value;

}
```

*appsettings.json*

```
 {
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "connectionstring here"
  },



  "EmailConfiguration": {
    "SmtpServer": "smtp.zoho.com",
    "SmtpPort": 587,
    "SmtpUsername": "username.zoho.com",
    "SmtpPassword": "password"
  },
    "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Loading appsettings.json into configuration(Startup.cs)

```
Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder ()
    .SetBasePath (env.ContentRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile ("appsettings.json", optional : true, reloadOnChange : true)
    .AddJsonFile ($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional : true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables ()
    .Build ();
```

Startup.cs // ConfigureServices()

```
services.Configure<EmailConfiguration>(Configuration);

services.AddSingleton<IEmailConfiguration> (Configuration.GetSection ("EmailConfiguration").Get<EmailConfiguration> ());
services.AddSingleton<IEmailConfiguration> (sp =>
        sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<EmailConfiguration>> ().Value
      );
```

*EmailConfiguration.cs*

```
public class EmailConfiguration : IEmailConfiguration {

    public EmailConfiguration(){

    }

    public string SmtpServer { get; set; }
    public int SmtpPort { get; set; }
    public string SmtpUsername { get; set; }
    public string SmtpPassword { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: @GugaTodua  `services.Configure<EmailConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("EmailConfiguration"));` note the `GetSection` call on configure. You are calling `Configure` on the **root**, not the desired section of the file

Comment: @Nkosi It worked. Will specifying GetSection("EmailConfiguration") affect other controllers where I am using other sections? Can I have two services.configure?

Comment: That call is specific to that section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling the `Configure` you needed to specify the section in order to bind the desired section of the settings file

```
services.Configure<EmailConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("EmailConfiguration"));
```

And since you now have the option registered and it looks like you also want to register it as a singleton consider the following

```
services.AddSingleton<IEmailConfiguration> (sp => 
    sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<EmailConfiguration>>().Value
);
```